# asymptotic notation

Tags: asymptotics, density-function

I have a  ( simple) question concerning  the asymptotic notation ( in the case of the variance of a kde): 
Assumptions are: 
$$ h \to 0 \ as\  n\to \infty\ s.t\   nh \to \infty $$

At some point i get $$ {E}[\cdot]- \frac{1}{n} [f(x) -O(h²)]² $$
which should should be transformd to 
$$ {E}[\cdot]- O\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
for some density function $f(x)$

My question would be if someone could tell me why the O-notation is $O(n^{-1})$ and not $O(\frac{h^4}{n})$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is nonzero, $O(h^2)$ is neglectible.

Answer (score 0):

With your hypothesis ($nh\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$), we know that $\;h=o\Bigl(\dfrac1n\Bigr)$, so  if $f(x)\ne 0$, $\;f(x)-O(h^2)\sim f(x)$, whence
$$\frac1n\bigl[f(x)-O(h^2)\bigr]\sim_\infty \frac{f(x)}n=O\Bigl(\frac1n\Bigr).$$